# How to get episodes from exact story

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have episode, which is related with story(foreign key) with url

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('', StoryView, basename='stories')
router.register('episodes', EpisodeView, basename='episodes')
```

View:

```
class EpisodeView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
```

models:

```
class Story(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location)
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre)
    author = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class Episode(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location)
    story = models.ForeignKey(Story, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    episode_number = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

I need to get episodes of story. How to do that is this case?

Comment: Please show your `models.py`

Comment: @pissall what exactly?

Comment: [Django Models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/)

Comment: @pissall in question

Answer (score 0):

you must add router to get episode id

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('', StoryView, basename='stories')
router.register('episodes', EpisodeView, basename='episodes')
router.register('(?P<story_id>[0-9]+)/episodes', StoryEpisodeView, basename='episodes')
```

then write update your list method for StoryEpisodeView:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Episode.objects.filter(story_id=self.story_id)

def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.story_id = kwargs.get(story_id)
    super(request, *args, **kwargs)
```